# Jquery Parent Frame

Tags: jquery, frame

In Javascript we access a frame's HTML element using the following code.

```
<br/>
var element;
element=parent.frames[0].document.getElementById("btnLogin");
```

How can we do this using Jquery?
Thanks, Ravi

Answer (score 5):

Something like

```
$('#btnLogin', parent.document).doYourThing();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have trouble with Same origin policy that prevent you modify document from another origin. But I don't know how to bypass it :P

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: How does this answer the question? The documents may well have the same origin. The question doesn't say "why can't I access this frame".